# How to prevent changing MatTab until confirmation?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-tab

I want to hold, the changing of `MatTab` until a confirmation is given. I have used `MatDialog` for confirmation. **The issue is, before clicking "Yes", the the tab is already changed.**

For example, From *income* tab, I click *adjustment* tab. And before switching to that tab, **I need to show the popup first**. But I am getting the popup after moving to *adjustment* tab.

[image: th image which show the popup]

component template:

```
 <mat-tab-group (click)="tabClick($event)">
  <mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let index = index" [label]="tab">
    <app-spread></app-spread
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

component ts (onClick's method):

```
tabClick(clickEvent: any) {
    if (clickEvent.target.innerText != 'First') {
      this.confirm();
    }
  }
  public async confirm() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmationDialogComponent, {
      maxHeight: '200px',
      maxWidth: '767px',
      width: '360px',
      disableClose: true,
      data: {
        title: 'Confirmation Message',
        content:
          'There are valid statements that are not Final. Set the statements as Final?'
      }
    });
    const res = dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      if (result === 1) {
        //TODO need to change the tab
      } else {
        //TODO no need to change the tab
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: You may find [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/2013) interesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometime ago I simulate a "mat-tab" in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68129174/how-to-force-mat-tab-body-to-render-bind-html-element-for-inactive-tab/68129729#68129729)

I Imagine that you can use this with only change the function

```
<mat-tab-group #tabgroup style="margin-bottom:5px;" 
               animationDuration="0"   mat-align-tabs="start"
               (selectedIndexChange)="change(tabgroup,$event)">
...
</mat-tab-group>
```

And the function change:

```
  change(tab:any,index:number)
  {
    if (tab.selectedIndex!=this.indexOld){
      const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(....)
      const res = dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
        if (result === 1) {
           this.index=index;
        } else {
           tab.selectedIndex=this.indexOld;
        }
      });
    }
    else
    {
       this.index=index;
    }
  }
```

See the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mbqbyo-p1lkii?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftab-group-align-example.ts) -in the stackblitz I simple use the confirm dialog-

**Update** problem if we use a mat-dialog.

There's another approach that it's overwrite the behaviour of the mat-tab-group

We need change the `_handleClick` function of the mat-tab-group, (see this function in [github](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/material/tabs/tab-group.ts)) and the function `_handleKeydown` of the mat-header (see this function in [github](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/material/tabs/paginated-tab-header.ts#L80)

It's a bit complex, but the only is get the mat-group using ViewChild
(I use `{static:true}` because my tabgroup is visible always.

```
@ViewChild('tabgroup', { static: true }) tabgroup: MatTabGroup;
```

Then, in ngOnInit (if it's not static:true, we use ngAfterViewInit), simply redefine the function. for this first "cast" to any this.tabgroup

First we makes a function alertDialog

```
  alertDialog(index:number,tab:MatTab,tabHeader:any,)
  {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
      data: {},
    });
    const res = dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
      if (result) {
        tabHeader.focusIndex = index;

        if (!tab.disabled) {
          this.tabgroup.selectedIndex = index;
        }
      }
    });

  }
```

Then, in ngOnInit we write

```
ngOnInit(){
    (this.tabgroup as any)._handleClick = (
      tab: MatTab,
      tabHeader: any,
      index: number
    ) => {
      if (this.tabgroup.selectedIndex != index)
        this.alertDialog(index, tab, tabHeader);
    };
}
```

To override the `_handleKeydown` we are enclosed all in setTimeout to give time to Angular to paint the mat-tab-header

```
  ngOnInit() {
    ....
    setTimeout(() => {
      const tabHeader = (this.tabgroup as any)._tabHeader;
      tabHeader._handleKeydown = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
        if (hasModifierKey(event)) {
          return;
        }

        switch (event.keyCode) {
          case ENTER:
          case SPACE:
            if (tabHeader.focusIndex !== tabHeader.selectedIndex) {
              const item = tabHeader._items.get(tabHeader.focusIndex);
              this.alertDialog(tabHeader.focusIndex, item, tabHeader);
            }
            break;
          default:
            tabHeader._keyManager.onKeydown(event);
        }
      };
    });
```

You can see in a [new stackblit](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mbqbyo-kkxsiv?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftab-group-align-example.ts)

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the change of the tab actually happens behind the dialogue, but you reverse the action. Looks weird from a user experience perspective. However, your solution in Stackblitz works as expected because you are using the browser confirm dialogue.

Comment: @Mojtaba: it's true. There a solution a bit complex that is override the_handleClick function of the mat-tab-group, and the function _handleKeydown of the mat-header. I update the answer

Answer (score 1):

Based in the update of the answer, why not create a Directive?

```
@Directive({
  selector:'mat-tab-group',
})
export class MatTabGroupExtends implements OnInit{
  @Output() beforeChange:EventEmitter<any>=new EventEmitter<any>()

  constructor(private tabgroup:MatTabGroup) {}
  ngOnInit()
  {
    if (this.beforeChange.observers.length && this.tabgroup)
    {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const tabHeader = (this.tabgroup as any)._tabHeader;
        tabHeader._handleKeydown = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
          if (hasModifierKey(event)) {
            return;
          }
  
          switch (event.keyCode) {
            case ENTER:
            case SPACE:
              if (tabHeader.focusIndex !== tabHeader.selectedIndex) {
                const item = tabHeader._items.get(tabHeader.focusIndex);
                if (!item.disabled)
                this.beforeChange.emit(tabHeader.focusIndex);
              }
              break;
            default:
              tabHeader._keyManager.onKeydown(event);
          }
        };
      });
  
      (this.tabgroup as any)._handleClick = (
        tab: MatTab,
        tabHeader: any,
        index: number
      ) => {
        if (this.tabgroup.selectedIndex != index && !tab.disabled)
        this.beforeChange.emit(index);
      };
    }
  }
}
```

As the selector is mat-tab-group we can use simply as

```
<!--see that the "event" is the "index", and 
                 "tabgroup" the template reference variable -->
<mat-tab-group #tabgroup (beforeChange)="alertDialog($event,tabgroup)">
   ...
</mat-tab-group>

 alertDialog(index:any,tabgroup:MatTabGroup) {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
      data: {},
    });
    const res = dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
      if (result) {
        tabgroup.selectedIndex=index
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: i think a directive is an excellent choice. by the way i set different selector: 'mat-tab-group[matTabGroupWithOuterChangeHandler]'

Answer (score 0):

My answer is based on Eliseo`s excellent answers with minor changes. without setTimeout and with minimum ANY

```
import { AfterViewInit, Directive, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTab, MatTabGroup } from '@angular/material/tabs';
import { ENTER, hasModifierKey, SPACE } from '@angular/cdk/keycodes';


@Directive({
  selector: 'mat-tab-group[matTabGroupWithOuterChangeHandler]',
})
export class MatTabGroupWithOuterChangeHandlerDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  @Output() outerChangeTabHandler: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();

  constructor(private tabGroup: MatTabGroup) {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.setCustomHandleKeyPress();
    this.setCustomHandleClick();
  }

  private setCustomHandleKeyPress(): void {
    const tabHeader = (this.tabGroup as any)._tabHeader;
    tabHeader._handleKeydown = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
      if (hasModifierKey(event)) {
        return;
      }

      switch (event.keyCode) {
        case ENTER:
        case SPACE:
          if (tabHeader.focusIndex !== tabHeader.selectedIndex) {
            const item = tabHeader._items.get(tabHeader.focusIndex);
            if (!item.disabled) {
              this.outerChangeTabHandler.emit(tabHeader.focusIndex);
            }
          }
          break;
        default:
          tabHeader._keyManager.onKeydown(event);
      }
    };
  }

  private setCustomHandleClick(): void {
    (this.tabGroup as any)._handleClick = (tab: MatTab, _, index: number) => {
      if (this.tabGroup.selectedIndex !== index && !tab.disabled) {
        this.outerChangeTabHandler.emit(index);
      }
    };
  }
}
```

html

```
<mat-tab-group 
    matTabGroupWithOuterChangeHandler
    [(selectedIndex)]="selectedIndex"
    (outerChangeTabHandler)="showLoseChangesModal($event)">
   ...
</mat-tab-group>
```

ts

```
public showLoseChangesModal(index:number) {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
      data: {},
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((ok) => {
      if (ok) {
        this.selectedIndex=index;
        this.cdr.detectChanges(); // if OnPush strategy
      }
    });
  }
```